# Which one of two versions of Xcode installed will be updated on updating?

Tags: xcode, macos

Hey guys i have installed two versions of Xcode (Xcode-5.0 and xcode-4.6) on my mac. Now my App Store showing updates for Xcode. If i am updating Xcode then which version will be updated (overridden).

Comment: For some time I prefer to update it manually, with rename of old version and make clean install.

Answer (score 1):

The one that has the name Xcode in your Applications folder. In my case, I had Xcode_4.6 and Xcode (5.0) in my Applications folder, and the 5.0 got updated.